# HTTP Error 404: Not Found - Post request not working

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, api, python-requests

Im trying to use postcode.io to get longitude and latitude from a bunch of postcodes by using the "Bulk lookup postcodes" that they have shown on the website https://postcodes.io/.

Im trying to pass a json object to the api point as they've shown in the documentation but keep getting the error shown in the title.

Here is my code;

```
allpostcodes = [i['postcode'] for i in _sortedstores()] # Getting postcodes from json file

data = {}
data['postcodes'] = allpostcodes # creating a dictionary and keeping `postcodes` and key and the postcode's as the value as shown in the example

_postcodearray = 'https://api.postcodes.io/%s' % json.dumps(data) # creating a json object and passing in the data
#_postcodearray = 'https://api.postcodes.io/%s' % data['postcodes'] #Not working



try:
    with urllib.request.urlopen(_postcodearray) as _postcodearray:
        a = _postcodearray.read()
        a = json.loads(a.decode('utf-8'))
        print(a)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

How my data varible looks before i use json.dump on it `{'postcodes': ['GU34 2QS', 'TN23 7DH', 'HP20 1DH']}`

I have also tried to regularly pass an array which resulted in the same error. Any help/suggestion on what i could be doing wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: can you show how your `data` variable looks like before the request?

Comment: @Vishal Sure, i will update my question with it at the bottom.

Comment: can you change the url to `_postcodearray = 'https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/%s' % json.dumps(data)` and try

Comment: @Vishal I actually did try that before and forgot to mention it, i still get the same error.

Comment: `postcodes` will definitely be there at the end. otherwise it is not a valid url. I tried with Postman app in my desktop and it is working fine.

Comment: what version of python you are using?

Comment: @Vishal i too just tried it and it seems like it is still not working for me, maybe im passing the data in wrong?

Comment: @Vishal Python 3.7.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import json
import urllib.request

allpostcodes = ["OX49 5NU", "M32 0JG", "NE30 1DP"]
#allpostcodes = [i['postcode'] for i in sortedstores] # Getting postcodes from json file

values = {}
# creating a dictionary and keeping `postcodes` and key and
# the postcode's as the value as shown in the example
values['postcodes'] = allpostcodes 

api_endpoint = 'https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/'
data = json.dumps(values).encode('utf8')
req = urllib.request.Request(api_endpoint, data,
        headers={'content-type': 'application/json'})
try:
    with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
        result = json.loads(response.read())
        print(json.dumps(result, indent=2))
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```